# Does reactjs extend javascript

Tags: reactjs

In the tutorial https://reactjs.org/tutorial/tutorial.html there is the following code

```
class Board extends React.Component {
  renderSquare(i) {
    return <Square value={i} />;
  }
```

The return statement has text within angled brackets that are not quoted. Does the reactjs code gets preprocessed before sent to javascript interpreter ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's called JSX. Using it, you can write HTML Elements without using literals or strings. During compiling, a transpiler like Babel convert it into a createElement Object, which React later uses to insert HTML Element into DOM.

Learn more about it here:
https://reactjs.org/docs/introducing-jsx.html

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is called JSX, and it is a syntax extension to JavaScript. It will be transpiled (most popuparly by Babel) into React's createElement syntax.